# Solving 2nd Order ODE w/Laplace Transforms + Heaviside

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

This is a similar problem to the one I posted earlier with some differences.[image]

**Attempt at solution:**

1. Write $g(t)$ as a heaviside function.
2. Take Laplace transform of LHS and RHS.
3. Solve for Y.
4. Take inverse laplace of Y. This gives me a function $y(t) = something$.

How do I change my answer that I get as $y(t)$ into the form they want in the image?

How do I write $g(t)$ as a Heaviside function?
I get $g(t) = t + (2\pi-t)u$, where $u$ is the Heaviside $u$ of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(t) $ should have the form in terms of Heaviside function

> $$g(t) = t u( 2\pi - t) + 2\pi u( t-2\pi).$$

Comment: Could you explain or show me how you got the that g(t)?